# Min value if multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a brief question I need some help with. I want to find the smallest value of an account number appearing multiple times, which I have done so successfully, nonetheless, I would like to know if I could fine the second lowest value if the min is 0. For example, take into consideration the following,

```
Account#  Charge
7063858   52.02
7063858   164.68
7067609    0.00
7067609   25.27
7067609   35.15
7067609    206.45
7780666    0.00
7780666   13.57

Formula:
={MIN(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))}
```

Using the above array formula, for the first two account numbers the min=52.02, which is fine, nonetheless, for the second set of account numbers the min=0.00, nonetheless, I would like it to return the second min that is not 0, i.e. 25.27, and finally for the last set of account numbers since there is no other min other than 0, due to there only being two accounts, I would get 0 back. Can I write a formula for this. Any and alll help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2019 or above, you can use something like this:

```
=MINIFS($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9,$A2,$B$2:$B$9,">0")
```

[image]

If you have an earlier version:

```
{=MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$9=$A2)*($B$2:$B$9>0),$B$2:$B$9))}
```